Show keymap with the help of cursor-sensor-functions
I'm experimenting with cursor-sensor-functions
(defun test-overlay-cursor (&rest args)
  (message "%S" args)
  (funcall-interactively 'which-key-show-keymap 'global-map))

(let ((overlays `(flycheck-info-overlay
                  flycheck-error-overlay
                  flycheck-warning-overlay)))
    (dolist (overlay overlays)
      (put overlay 'cursor-sensor-functions '(test-overlay-cursor))

When moving the cursor over a flycheck error it should display a message and show the global-map keymap.
When moving the cursor to a character with a flycheck overlay emacs freezes (the cursor doesn't move):

The message appears briefly and is then replaced with the first line of (which-key-show-keymap 'global-map) and if I press any key emacs unfreezes and displays the following error:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  redisplay--pre-redisplay-functions(t)
  redisplay_internal\ \(C\ function\)()
  read-key-sequence-vector(nil nil t nil nil t)
  read-key()
  which-key--show-keymap("global-map" (keymap #^[nil nil keymap <shortened >...))
  which-key-show-keymap(global-map)
  funcall-interactively(which-key-show-keymap global-map)
  test-overlay-cursor(#<window 3 on main.ml> 46 entered)
  cursor-sensor--detect()

I tested with emacs -Q and I have the same behaviour. If I remove the (which-key ...) part, no bug/freeze appears. It looks like I'm not supposed to call a function that creates a new buffer.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Sorry about that :'(

No problem.....
